# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when use arraylist.map() with kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception, kotlin-coroutines

This is my function to get assets item

```
fun getAccessoriesFromAssets() {
    view.onAccessoriesLoaded(false)
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val tempCategoryList: ArrayList<String> =
            (view as BodyFaceEditorActivity).assets.list("accessories")?.toCollection(ArrayList()) ?: arrayListOf()
        tempCategoryList.map { categoryPath ->
            accessoryCategoriesFromAssets.add(AccessoryCategory(categoryPath, categoryPath))
            async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val tempItemList: ArrayList<String> =
                    view.assets.list("accessories/$categoryPath")?.toCollection(ArrayList())
                        ?: arrayListOf()
                tempItemList.map { itemPath ->
                    accessoryItemsFromAssets.add(
                        AccessoryItem(categoryPath, itemPath, false)
                    )
                }
            }
        }.awaitAll()
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) { view.onAccessoriesLoaded(true) }
    }
}
```

Sometimes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException happened (run 100 times, happened 1 time), so I think I have a problem with Coroutines. But what is this?

Logcat said the error was in this line

```
accessoryItemsFromAssets.add(
   AccessoryItem(categoryPath, itemPath, false)
)
```

This is my assets folder structure

```
/accessories
  |
  |____/pack1
  |      |
  |      |_item1.png
  |      |_item2.png
  |      |_...
  |____/pack2
         |
         |_item1.png
         |_item2.png
         |_...
```

Thanks for your helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a bunch of coroutines with `async` then all those coroutines will be running at the same time. In Java collections are not threadsafe by default. So if you make all those coroutines update the same collection it will fail randomly. You should make `accessoryItemsFromAssets` threadsafe by wrapping it (on creation) with `Colletions.synchronizedCollection()`.